# jQuery extend plugin settings with data attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I have managed to modify simple number spinner plugin to use `data-attribute` for settings. Here is the part of the code

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.simpleSpinner = function(options) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            size: 'large',
            step: 1,
        }, $(this).data('spinner'), options);

        return this.each(function(e) {
            var self = $(this);
            ......

        });
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Then I initialize plugin like:

```
$(function() {
   $('.spinner').simpleSpinner();
});
```

```html
<input class="spinner" type="number" value="1" min="1" max="10" data-spinner='{"size":"large"}'>
<input class="spinner" type="number" value="1" min="1" max="10" data-spinner='{"size":"small"}'>
```

This all works fine, except that if I have more then one element, then `data-attributes` are applied to all of them from first element.

I would like to be able to individually control each element using size in `data-spinner` without the need of having two instances of plugin,

```
$('.spinner2').simpleSpinner();
```

with different class assigned to it.

Answer (score 0):

Just insert your setting initialization code where you are looping through the elements

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.simpleSpinner = function(options) {
    return this.each(function(e) {
      var $self = $(this);
      var settings = $.extend({
        size: 'large',
        step: 1,
      }, $self.data('spinner'), options);
      
      $self.after($("<pre/>",{text:JSON.stringify(settings)}))
    });
  };
}(jQuery));

$(function() {
  $('.spinner').simpleSpinner();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="spinner" type="number" value="1" min="1" max="10" data-spinner='{"size":"large"}'>

<input class="spinner" type="number" value="1" min="1" max="10" data-spinner='{"size":"small"}'>

<input class="spinner" type="number" value="1" min="1" max="10" data-spinner='{"size":"lorem"}'>

<input class="spinner" type="number" value="1" min="1" max="10" data-spinner='{"size":"ipsum"}'>
```